# How to analyze Process Explorer's graphs and data?

Tags: windows, performance

How can i tell which apps are hogging all of my IO ops, or stealing too much of memory using the Process Explorer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to **View** > **Select Columns...** and open the **Process Performance** tab and add the I/O ops you wish to be displayed. Then open the **Process Memory** tab and make your selections there.

Answer (score 1):

You just need Task Manager:

Go to Processes, menu entry View / Select Columns, and check either or all:

CPU Usage (gives percentage of total CPU in use)
Memory - Working Set (memory in use)
i/O Reads + I/O writes (counts total number of disk accesses done)

Comment: Task Manager isn't nearly as helpful as Process Explorer.  Clearly this person is looking for help using PE instead of Task Manager

Comment: @gadzooks64: Simple solutions are best. Many people overlook the power of Task Manager. No need to downvote a helpful comment.

Comment: @harrymc I would have done the same thing if the OP had asked for help with Excel and someone replied with a solution suggesting they use Open Office.

Comment: @gadzooks64: Not the same thing. Task Manager is standard in Windows and can be launched in more ways (ctrl-alt-del). It should be the preferred tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can click twice on the CPU column header to sort the process from highest to lowest based on CPU usage.

The same can be done with I/O columns once you have selected them as Molly suggested.